# Will getaddrinfo() on the host ever return more than one IPv4 address?

Tags: c++, sockets

Say I call `getaddrinfo()` as below:

```
addrinfo hints;
addrinfo* res = NULL;

hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

getaddrinfo(NULL, "http", &hints, &res);
```

Is it currently possible for the results of this to contain more than one result with an IPv4 address? The only reason I could think of is possibly multiple devices with separate connections, but I'm half expecting it to only return the address of the primary connection or the one connection it happens to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

**The [man page on getaddrinfo](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo) has following to say on the topic**

There are several reasons why the linked list may have more than one addrinfo structure, including: the network host is multihomed, accessible over multiple protocols (e.g. both AF_INET and AF_INET6); or the same service is available from multiple socket types (one SOCK_STREAM address and another SOCK_DGRAM address, for example). Normally, the application should try using the addresses in the order in which they are returned. The sorting function used within getaddrinfo() is defined in RFC 3484; the order can be tweaked for a particular system by editing /etc/gai.conf (available since glibc 2.5).

Comment: I understand that other hosts can return multiple addresses through multihoming, but I was wondering if it was possible when called on your local machine.

Comment: Err... I see (although a comment would be nice). Still: it is trivially possible. Just add multiple entries for, say, "http" to your /etc/services. I have two for "https", for example. And it is the same for your local machine, of course. It is about names, not about number of interfaces.

Comment: Hm, I see. I really just used `"http"` as an example. I never actually have used the common protocol names, and have just used port numbers. So, since http has many ports associated to it, will the results of http contain an addrinfo structure for each possible port? If not, how would having multiple entries in /etc/services change anything?

Comment: I think they will have an entry for each port, with si_addrinfo containing the information. The manpage of getaddrinfo almost confirms this, although my copy only talks explicitly about SOCK_DGRAM vs SOCK_STREAM

Comment: I have 3 entries in /etc/services for http, and getaddrinfo() only returns 1 result.

Comment: That's because only one matches your hints (BTW, there is no ai_flag AF_UNSPEC).

Comment: Haha, fat fingered it. I meant AI_PASSIVE. The code I was running was using AI_PASSIVE for a flag. And yeah, I see what you're saying. Wasn't paying much attention to the protocol part of services. So it's possible, but shouldn't really happen unless someone added unofficial entries to their services file? Wouldn't this create unexpected behavior for anyone to do this, anyways?

Comment: Also, you mentioned RFC34384 specifies the sorting. I noticed that my code would sometimes return the same list on Linux and Solaris, but in different order. Since the order was also the same across multiple flavors of Linux, Windows, and even an embedded system, is it safe to assume Solaris wasn't up to standard on that point? I don't believe the system nor its toolchain were necessarily up-to-date.

Comment: **re unofficial entries:** it might be unexpected to some programs. OTOH, one might say, that the programs are not supporting their configuration fully as it the interface explicitly designed to return multiple entries. **re sorting:** Take a look at the /etc/gai.conf, maybe it helps. Maybe Solaris was just configured differently. OTOH, again, Solaris is also known to have its own differences

Answer (score 1):

I had this confusion too and I did some research.

Quoted from *The Linux Programming Interface*

```
int getaddrinfo(const char * host , const char * service ,
const struct addrinfo * hints , struct addrinfo ** result );
```

> The result argument returns a list of structures, rather than a single
>   structure, because there may be multiple combinations of host and
>   service corresponding to the criteria specified in `host`, `service`, and
>   `hints`. **For example, multiple address structures could be returned for
>   a host with more than one network interface**.

I tested with my own domain `copyqwer.com`

DNS setting:

```
Type    Name        Value               TTL 
A       @           23.106.150.74       600 seconds 
A       @           111.222.17.173      600 seconds
```

and `getaddrinfo` returns addr structures with these 2 different ip address.

A full example. https://onlinegdb.com/ry1cdoAKr

Output on my computer (I don't know why there's no `UDP` ouput on my local computer, but that doesn't matter)

```
/home/*****/CLionProjects/APUE/cmake-build-debug/APUE copyqwer.com http
flags canon family inet type stream protocol TCP
    host copyqwer.com address 111.222.17.173 port 80
flags canon family inet type stream protocol TCP
    host - address 23.106.150.74 port 80
```